# In a groupoid G, is G(x,y) called a coset of the automorphism group G(x,x)?

Tags: group-theory, category-theory

In isomorphism problems one often has a pair $(x,y)$ of objects in a category $\mathcal{C}$ and wants to describe the set $\mathrm{iso}(x,y)$ of isomorphisms $x\to y$ in the category.  This is impractical as $|\mathrm{iso}(x,y)|$ can be exponentially larger than the data used to describe $x$ and $y$. The remedy:

$$\mathrm{iso}(x,y)=\mathrm{aut}(x)\phi$$

where $\mathrm{aut}(x)=\mathrm{iso}(x,x)$ is the group of automorphisms of $x$ and $\phi:x\to y$ is any element of $\mathrm{iso}(x,y)$.  In general a group can be prescribed by a set of generators which is logarithmic in the order of the group (for countable infinite groups a finite generating sets would be your cut down).

Well in the expositions one wants to say what you are doing is a making $\mathrm{iso}(x,y)$ a coset of $\mathrm{aut}(x)$ -- it appeals to things already known and trusted.  But that doesn't really make sense as its not inside some larger group.  Rather it is inside a groupoid -- the groupoid of all invertible morphisms in $\mathcal{C}$.  I see that groupoids give names to $\mathrm{aut}(x)$, things like **automorphism group** or Wikipedia says **vertex groups**.

Is it permissible to call $\mathrm{iso}(x,y)$ a **coset** in the groupoid?  If not, is there a name for $\mathrm{iso}(x,y)$ other than "hom-set in the groidoid"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're looking for group-theoretic points of view on the situation, I think what you're looking for is that, if it's nonempty, then $\mathrm{iso}(x,y)$ is an $\mathrm{aut}(x)$-torsor.

Comment: I agree $\mathrm{iso}(x,y)$ is a torsor, just as it is also a regular $G$-set.  What I am after is a term that invites one to think of an ambient space in which $\mathrm{iso}(x,y)$ lies relative to $aut(x)$.  E.g. a coset lies in some larger group. This is helpful as you can declare that the ambient space is good for computation.   Neither torsors nor $G$-sets live anywhere so you are back to the problem of individually prescribing how these sets are represented. Is there no name for $G(x,y)$ in a groupoid relative to $G(x,x)$?

Comment: @Algeboy: The fundamental intuition, IMO, is that $\mathrm{iso}(x,y)$, $\mathrm{aut}(x)$, and $\mathrm{aut}(y)$ are all the "same thing", you're just looking at it differently. E.g. a connected groupoid is *equivalent* to a group (i.e. a groupoid with one object).

Comment: For some math I'd agree, but my problem is for of rigorous discussion of isomorphism problems;  i.e. to tighten up vague colloquial statements like "same things".  E.g. One cannot simply say "Isomorphism of abelian groups is solved by...."  Does this mean to find one isomorphism? or all? Is it yes/no or a physical isomorphism? etc.  Also how are groups given? etc. Groupoids appear to offer good modernized vocabulary to supplement the status quo lingo. I am just exploring if one can say something like "The groupoid of abelian permutation groups has computable cosets" or something like that.

Comment: Thanks for the discussion Hurkyl, which seem to confirm the hypothesis that  groupoid vocabulary gets by with the similarly deficient vocabulary of other fields.  So I'll mark it as answered but would welcome any future remarks indicating the introduction of suitable vocabulary that references both the group that acts, and the ambient groupoid in which the structure itself lives, in a manner similar to our familiar coset vocabulary.